# Adding in view to laxicity parallax plugin

Tags: jquery, parallax, inview

I'm currently trying to add some nice parallax effects to some of the elements on a site I'm working on.

I've found a plugin called Laxicity (http://www.gougouzian.fr/projects/jquery/laxicity/) which does everything I need in terms of the parallax options / effects.

However the one problem I have is that on long pages, the parallax effect happens before the element is in view.

What I want to do is add some additional functionally to check wether the element is in view before applying Parallax effect.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be brilliant.

Thanks.

Andrew

Comment: The demo page of the plugin you link to does not really seem to work? Maybe try another plugin or build it yourself?